# Grab redirect Url with file_get_content()

Tags: php, laravel, domparser

Having some trouble to grabbing redirect link with `file_get_content` I used these codes: the `$link` has a couple urls.

```
foreach ($link as $site) {
            if (strpos($site, 'https://www.mecsumai.com/') === 0) {
                $dom = getSiteContent($site);
                $div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
                if ($div->length > 0) {
                    $iframeLink[] = $div[0]->getAttribute('src');
                }
            }
        }
```

I grabbed here iframe urls which is like this:

```
https://www.mecsumai.com/bkn-summary?bid=16078001&bg1=999999&bg2=dddddd&wdt=100%&aln=center
```

But when try to enter this with `file_get_content`. I can't get the content of page. Because it will redirecting to this, when you try to enter:

```
https://www.mecsumai.com/bkn-summary/?bid=16078001&bg1=999999&bg2=dddddd&wdt=100%25&aln=center&newid=06078001
```

Last `newid=line...` is redirecting part. So I try this.

```
foreach($iframeLink as $results){
            $opts = array('https' =>
                array(
                    'follow_location' => 1,
                )
            );
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);
            $lastUrl[] = file_get_contents($results, false, $context);

        }

        print_r($lastUrl);
```

I'm getting no error, also getting the page content but not the whole of [this](https://www.mecsumai.com/bkn-summary/?bid=16078001&bg1=999999&bg2=dddddd&wdt=100%25&aln=center&newid=06078001) page. The table is not coming? 
Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if `file_get_contents` allow such option, however you can use curl which does.

Here is an example.

```
function curl_get_contents($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: yup, normally love a single `file_get_contents()` vs. the whole `curl` thing for what should be a simple GET operation, but sometimes you just gotta use `curl`...